# Tagging of symlinks

Tags: macos, symlink, finder-tag

Is it possible to tag a symlink using the new OS X Mavericks tagging functionality (old labels functionality)?

When I select a symlink in Finder, File => Tags... option is grayed-out.

Is it possible somehow through Terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you can't tag symlinks. But you can tag the original, then symlink information shows all tags from original.

If you need separately tagging in different colors you can tag aliases of original file.